# REACT using Ref

Tags: reactjs, ref

is it true, the purpose of Ref is replacing document.getElementById??

Once i apply react, i should not use  document.getElementById to access DOM to get data?

i found some article said that we can apply the  **this.refs** to access the DOM

```
   <input  ref="test" value="option" id="option4"/>

   console.log(this.refs.test);
```

But it can only run within the method within the component,
what if i want show the input value in console (developer Tools)?

Comment: that's look like an old writing go to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) and write it like you should

Answer (score 0):

It is true in a way, because react uses its virtual dom and diffing algorithm to watch changes and reflect in dom. If you use direct api to access dom. react could not access it in its virtual dom.

Thats why they have an unique ***id*** or ***keys*** just like in DOM to manipulate elements (components) as ***node***.

If you see in confirm-alert components used in npm packages, they will create an element and render it as an element by using ***ReactDOM***. As soon the toaster is finished it is not removed directly from the ***DOM***.

First it is made to be find from the ***reactVirtualDom*** by using api ***findDomNode*** at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode

then it is  unmounted using ***unmountComponentAtNode***.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode

For example: ***https://github.com/GA-MO/react-confirm-alert/blob/master/src/index.js***

So, refs are used to overcome direct DOM manipulation and changes that affect or effects the react rendering process.